# Can sed replace new line characters?

Tags: sed

Is there an issue with sed and new line character?
I have a file test.txt with the following contents

```
aaaaa  
bbbbb  
ccccc  
ddddd
```

The following does not work:
`sed -r -i 's/\n/,/g' test.txt`

I know that I can use `tr` for this but my question is why it seems not possible with sed.

If this is a side effect of processing the file line by line I would be interested in why this happens. I think `grep` removes new lines. Does sed do the same?

Comment: In this case sed might be not the best tool to use (eg. "tr"). There are tools that are more intuitive, easier to read/maintain, performing better (especially on big data) etc. ... Don't use your hammer to put the screws in (even if it works). You can find a comparison on:
[http://slash4.de/blog/python/sed-replace-newline-or-python-awk-tr-perl-xargs.html](http://slash4.de/blog/python/sed-replace-newline-or-python-awk-tr-perl-xargs.html)

Comment: `tr` would add a trailing `,` and would output an unterminated line. Best is to use `paste` instead: `paste  -sd , test.txt`

Comment: Updated link in comment by @omoser: https://web.archive.org/web/20151102021030/https://slash4.de/blog/python/sed-replace-newline-or-python-awk-tr-perl-xargs.html

Answer (score 72, accepted):

With GNU `sed` and provided `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment (for single-line input):

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' test.txt
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n :

1. create a label via `:a`
2. append the current and next line to the pattern space via `N`
3. if we are before the last line, branch to the created label `$!ba` (`$!` means not to do it on the last line (as there should be one final newline)).
4. finally the substitution replaces every newline with a comma on the pattern space (which is the whole file).

Comment: This seems to indicate that the problem is that sed reads line by line.But I can't understand why is this an issue.It could just read the line and replace the new line character (or last character) with a ,

Comment: @jim It looks like it is not in the buffer to be matched, but I am not fluent with sed, maybe someone else can shed a light on that. I think you should extend your Q with that specific info, so people are more likely to read it, and hopefully answer.

Comment: This results in `ba: Event not found`

Comment: @krb686 What is the "This" you are referring to? Did you run the above `sed` command with those exact options? On what `test.txt ` file? With which version of `sed` (try `sed --version`)?

Comment: @Anthon Sorry, I think I meant to say "the".  I read another SO post that informed me that csh requires me to escape the `!`.  Interestingly, that still did not work for me and I ended up having to double escape the `!` in my `.csh` script.  So I don't really have a problem at the moment, but you do you know why that might be? What worked for me was `sed :a;N;$\\!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

Comment: Note that that syntax is GNU specific, and even with GNU `sed`, if POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment and the input has only one line, there will be no output.

Comment: this doesn't answer any of OP's three questions.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas When you say GNU specific you mean the `\n` in the substitute command?

Comment: @dev, no. That `\n` is standard. It's the `-i`, the `:a;...`, `ba;...` (in many sed implementation including the original one, `;` is part of the label), and the assumption that `N` doesn't exit `sed` on the last line. Also, many non-GNU sed implementations have a limit on the size of their pattern space (that solution loads the whole file in it before substituting)

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas. While `echo 'hello\nworld' | gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g'` worked on my macOS, I tried BSD `sed` just for the fun of it. Like you said, it was using `;` after a label that caused the command to fail. The working equivalent for non-GNU would be `echo 'hello\nworld' | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/, /g'`. And of course, as you point out in a separate comment, non-GNU will produce no output if input is `echo 'hello'`.

Answer (score 97):

This works with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g'
```

[`-z`](https://archive.li/RKR6y#selection-1971.0-1971.2) is included since 4.2.2

NB. `-z` changes the delimiter to null characters (`\0`). If your input does not contain any null characters, the whole input is treated as a single line. This can come with its [limitations](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html).

To avoid having the newline of the last line replaced, you can change it back:

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/'
```

(Which is GNU `sed` syntax again, but it doesn't matter as the whole thing is GNU only)

Answer (score 15):

`sed` always removes the trailing `\n`ewline just before populating pattern space, and then appends one before writing out the results of its script. A `\n`ewline can be had in pattern-space by various means - but never if it is not the result of an edit. This is important - `\n`ewlines in `sed`'s pattern space always reflect a change, and never occur in the input stream. `\n`ewlines are the only delimiter a `sed`der can count on with unknown input.

If you want to replace all `\n`ewlines with commas and your file is not very large, then you can do:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;y/\n/,/'
```

That appends every input line to `h`old space - except the first, which instead overwrites `h`old space - following a `\n`ewline character. It then `d`eletes every line not the `$!`last from output. On the last line `H`old and pattern spaces are e`x`changed and all `\n`ewline characters are `y///`translated to commas.

For large files this sort of thing is bound to cause problems - `sed`'s buffer on line-boundaries, that can be easily overflowed with actions of this sort.

Comment: The fact that `d` deletes the pattern space and starts the next cycle is crucially important here (that is, for all but the last line, `x;y/\n/,/` is ignored).

Answer (score 11):

From Oracle's web site:

> The sed utility works by sequentially reading a file, line by line, into memory. It then performs all actions specified for the line and places the line back in memory to dump to the terminal with the requested changes made. After all actions have taken place to this one line, it reads the next line of the file and repeats the process until it is finished with the file.

Basically this means that because sed is reading line by line the newline character is not matched.

The solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n is:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
```

or, in a portable version (without `;` concatening after jump mark labels)

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g'
```

An explanation into how that works is provided on that page.

Comment: Note that that syntax is GNU specific, and even with GNU `sed`, if POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment and the input has only one line, there will be no output.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually two questions on your post:

> Can sed replace new line characters?

Yes. Absolutely yes. Any sed could do:

```
s/\n/,/g
```

or

```
y/\n/,/
```

That will transform any newline (that got into the pattern space) into commas.

> Is there an issue with sed and new line character?

Yes, there are several issues with the newline character in sed:

- By default, sed will place in the pattern space a valid **line**. Some seds have limits on the length of a line and on accepting NUL bytes. A line ends on a newline. So, as soon as a newline is found on the input, the input gets split, then sed **removes the newline** and places what is left in the pattern space. So, most of the time, no newline gets into the pattern space.
- Only by an edit of the pattern space is a newline added/inserted/edited in.
- Almost always, a newline is appended to each consecutive output of sed.
- The GNU sed is able to avoid printing a trailing newline if the **last** line of the input is missing the newline.
- Only GNU sed is able to use another delimiter instead of newline (namely NUL bytes with the -z option).

All the above points make it difficult to "convert newlines" to anything.
And, if newlines are replaced with another text character, then sed **must** contain the whole text file in memory (whatever process was used to get there).

A couple of solutions that capture the whole file in memory in sed are:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;y/\n/,/'   file      # most seds. [1]
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'   file      # GNU sed.   
sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' file      # GNU sed.
```

A couple of fast solutions that doesn't use much memory are:

```
tr '\n' ',' file ; echo
awk '{printf("%s%s",NR==1?"":",",$0)}END{print ""}' file
```

---

<sup>1</sup>From sed solutions: For every line, H adds the line to the hold space (except that the first line completely replace the hold space (avoid a leading newline)), then the pattern space is erased with `$!d` (except on the last line). On that last line, which was not erased, the rest of commands gets executed. First, get all the lines captured in the hold space with `x` and then, replace all newlines with a comma with `y/\n/,/`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use a slightly simpler syntax:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/,/g;ba'
```

...just changing sequence order.

Comment: But runs the `s` command for each input line on a pattern space that is increasingly big.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to replace newlines by `\n`. I wanted to do that, so here's what I did:

```
(echo foo; echo bar; echo baz) | sed -r '$!s/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n' 
# Output: foo\nbar\nbaz
```

Here's what it does: for all lines *except the last*, append `\n`. Then, delete newlines with `tr`.

Comment: `-r` is only available in GNU `sed`, not BSD.

Answer (score 1):

There's some very nice *sed* magic here. And some good points raised about pattern space overflow. I love to use *sed* even when it's not the simplest way, because it's so compact and powerful. However it has it's limitations, and for large amounts of data the pattern space would have to be mahoosive.

GNU says this:

> For those who want to write portable sed scripts, be aware that some implementations have been known to limit line lengths (for the pattern and hold spaces) to be no more than 4000 bytes. The posix standard specifies that conforming sed implementations shall support at least 8192 byte line lengths. GNU sed has no built-in limit on line length; as long as it can malloc() more (virtual) memory, you can feed or construct lines as long as you like.
>
> However, recursion is used to handle subpatterns and indefinite repetition. This means that the available stack space may limit the size of the buffer that can be processed by certain patterns.

I don't have much to add, but I would like to point you towards my go-to guide for *sed*. It's excellent.
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

and here is my solution:

```
for i in $(cat test.txt); do echo -n $i','; done; echo '' >> somewhere
```

well it works

Comment: You might want to read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and maybe [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819)

Answer (score 0):

To replace *newline* with *comma*, you can try this (csh):

```
foreach i (`cat test.txt`)
  echo -n "$i ,"
end
```

Comment: The user knows they can do this task with `tr`, but asks whether it can be done using `sed`. The question is about `sed` rather than about some other way of performing the same task.