# How can I replace a newline with sed?

Tags: sed, newlines

I've got text with whitespace (including a newline) that I need to replace. I'd like to use `sed`, but AIX doesn't seem to support the [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters) to `sed` newline questions I found. The version of bash I'm using is "GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1)"

If I run a command that outputs a bunch of pairs of lines of text like:

```
alias:  aliasname
                10:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

What is the best way to make it one line for each? If I use `ssh user@system command | tr '\n' ' '`, it replaces both newlines, and I need to keep the last one or else the output goes into a single line.

Edit: what I've tried so far is:

- `| sed -e ':1' -e 'N' -e '$!b1' -e 's/\n/ /g'` which replaces all the newlines, putting the entire output stream into a single line.
- `| while read i; do printf "%s " $i; done; echo` which also replaces all the newlines
- `| tr -d '\n'` and `| tr -d '\n'; echo`, which still replace all newlines, however the echo adds one back at the last command.

Comment: Is there any sort of pattern to what appears on the lines? Like, is the first line always `alias:  aliasname` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pure bash approach that will delete the first newline of every pair:

```
command | 
  while IFS=$'\n' read i; do 
    let c++; [ "$(expr $c % 2)" -eq "0" ] && echo "$i" || printf "%s " "$i"; 
  done
```

If you don't need to keep the whitespace unchanged, you can leave out the `IFS`:

```
command | 
  while read i; do 
    let c++; [ "$(expr $c % 2)" -eq "0" ] && echo "$i" || printf "%s " "$i"; 
  done
```

The same idea using `perl`:

```
command | perl -ne 'chomp;$. % 2 == 0 ? print "$_\n" : print "$_"'
```

Comment: Thanks, like you said in chat: ugly, but functional and portable ;)

Comment: (1) `IFS="\n"` doesn’t work.  (Perhaps you meant `IFS=$'\n'`? But why not just `IFS=`?)  `IFS="\n"` seems to be equivalent to `IFS=n`.  If a line of input contains exactly one `n`, and it is the last character on the line, it will be stripped.  (Try your name, for example.)  (2) Your script fails in the pathological case that the last line of the input doesn’t end with a newline.  (3) Seriously?  You’re using `expr`?  In a loop?

Comment: @G-Man (1) you're absolutely right, no idea what I was thinking. It does actually produce the expected output with the OP's example, which is why I didn't realize at the time. I wanted `\n` to leave other whitespace unchanged. (2) yes, but this shouldn't be done in the shell in the first place. I was going through a shell phase at the time and was interested in shell-only solutions. Silly though. (3) Why not? it's slow and inefficient, yes (see (2)), but if you're going for slow and inefficient (shell) anyway, why not?

Answer (score 5):

Easyest

```
ssh user@system command | tr '\n' ' ';echo
```

Or if you want `sed`

```
ssh user@system command | sed 'N;s/\n\s\+/ /'
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't replace the newline.

Comment: @Basil Show the exact line by `ssh user@system command | cat -A - `

Comment: `cat: Not a recognized flag: A`

Version of bash is:
`GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1)`

Comment: @Basil OK, you haven't GNU utilites. What you can receive on `ssh user@system command | hd`

Comment: "hd"? That's not installed... what's it supposed to do? I googled around and only found stuff that didn't seem relevant.

Comment: @Basil `hd (hexdump)` show all chars in hex, octal, ascii etc codes. May be you have `od`?

Comment: @Costas `od` is POSIX, which is all you can count on on AIX. `hd` is a BSD utility.

Comment: Thanks guys! This is a really useful tool I learned about :) The output of an `od -a` shows me the characters `ht  lf  ht  ht` between the lines I need to replace. The output of a straight `od` is `005011 004465 030072 030066`.

Comment: I should clarify- that tr worked, but it puts all the lines into a single massive line. I edited the question, realizing that I hadn't explained the stream well- I'm getting an arbitrary number of pairs of lines that I'd like to turn into one line each. If this were linux, I'd use sed to replace the particular whitespace pattern between lines in a pair.

Comment: The question talks about ``tr '\n' ' '`` and ``s/\n/ /g``, so the OP obviously wants to replace newlines with spaces on a one-to-one basis — so why does your second answer replace a newline only if it is followed (at the beginning of the next line) with one or more whitespace characters, and then delete those character(s)?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sed -e ':1' -e 'N' -e '$!b1' -e 's/\n/ /g'
```

Comment: I tried this and got `sed: 0602-417 The label :1;N;$!b1;s/\n/ /g is greater than eight characters.`

Comment: @Basil GNU sed allows `;` in more places than AIX sed. Use a newline or separate `-e` arguments (see my edit).

Comment: I tried it with the new version and instead of an error message, I got all my text on one line again, as if I had done a `tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 0):

It probably best to do this with `sed`;
see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216) 
For example, this minor variation of [Costas’s second (`sed`) answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165019/80216#165023):

```
sed 'N; s/\n/ /'
```

does a pretty good job of answering the question:
`N` to append the next line of input into the pattern space,
and then `s/\n/ /` to do the substitution. 
(And then these commands repeat for every two lines of input.)

But, if you want to do it entirely in the shell,
this variation of [terdon’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165019/80216#165283):

```
while IFS= read -r line1
do
    IFS= read -r line2; printf '%s %s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
done
```

works without running any external program(s). 
The logic is (IMHO) simple:
while not at the end of the input, read a line, and then read another line,
and then output the two strings, separated by spaces, on one line.

The above code has a problem with an edge case:
if the input is an even number of well-formed lines
followed by some characters not terminated with a newline,
it discards the final (partial) line. 
([terdon’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165019/80216#165283) has the same issue,
but not just for even numbers of lines.) 
This is because `read` returns failure when it reads a partial line,
even though it does put the data into the variable. 
So the fix is this:

```
while IFS= read -r line1  ||  [ "$line1" != "" ]
do
    IFS= read -r line2; printf '%s %s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
done
```

which keeps going until `read` fails
*and* sets the variable to an empty string.