# How to remove ^M and proceeding lines from a text file?

Tags: sed, cat

I have following lines with ^M (return carriage). I want to remove ^M+proceeding line. You can notice there is a new line after each ^M, which is not desired. I purpose is to remove control character and make one line CSV.

```
    '1.0';'';'';'';'Mon Jul 04 00:00:00 CEST 2016';'To cash Pls Acc 4142^M
To cash Pls Acc 4142';'To cash Pls Acc 4142^M
Money';'236159';'236159';'-2000.0';'';'2000.0'
```

I tried following but didn't work. NOTE: ^M = CONTROL v + CONTRL m

`cat file.csv | sed 's/[\^M\n]//g' > new_file.csv`

above lines removed ^M but the line is still broken with new line.

**expected output**

```
 '1.0';'';'';'';'Mon Jul 04 00:00:00 CEST 2016';'To cash Pls Acc 4142To cash Pls Acc 4142';'To cash Pls Acc 4142 Money';'236159';'236159';'-2000.0';'';'2000.0'
```

Comment: I believe you should replace the end of the line as well. Try adding $ to the left side of the substitution

Comment: There are several tool available to replace Windows newlines with Unix newlines. Look for `dos2unix` for example.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus added expected out put

Answer (score 3):

This works for your case:

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n//g' file.csv
```

From: [Can sed replace new line characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters)

Or this one:

```
sed -e :a -e '/\r$/N; s/\r\n//; ta' file.csv
```

From: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Note that you don't need to use `cat`, and you can directly edit your file with the option `-i` if you want.

Comment: I am still getting output file ^M after running above.  sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\^M\n//g' file.csv > file_without_m.csv.

Comment: Try replacing `\^M` with `\r`

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer. But remember: use the `-i` option only if you want to directly modify `file.csv`. If you just want to redirect output to `file_without_m.csv` you don't need `-i`.

Answer (score -1):

It's `\r` not `^M`. The simplest way to do it is:

```
tr -d '\n-\r' < file.
```

`-d` means delete and `\n-\r` is the character range for `tr`uncation.

Note that this code will also remove occurrences of `\n`s not preceded by "`^M`"s.

Comment: About the downvoting. Without an explanation, my only suspicion is that you found my answer redundant. I think the simplest method is a good answer to add.